# Changing text-format for body field

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I've installed Drupal 8 in a minimal installation; I've enabled CKeditor and created a text-format called "Full". I've also created a role named as "Administrator" and gave it all permissions available whatsoever; After that, I've attached my user "Admin" to that role "Administrator" and associated it with my newly created text-format ("Full"). I than decided I'm good to keep on:

After I did all of this I went to my content type and clicked to edit it's body field... When I went in to the edit screen I didn't see any place to attach the new text format I created to it, so where is the right place to set the field for other text-format rather than the default "plain text"?

[image]

Comment: There are several usability issues in the works to make all of this work better.  See [Allow text field to enforce a specific text format](https://www.drupal.org/node/784672) and [Default text formats are not saved properly without accompanying values](https://www.drupal.org/node/1278886) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using it, default text-only shows up when there is no other choice.

If you add another format: ie: "test", now you will see in the drop down CKEditor and test.

Also, you probably did not select CKeditor as your text editor. Did you enable the CKeditor module?

[image]

**I highly recommend not using minimal installation. I just tried it and a lot of the modules are disabled, just figuring this stuff out it's quite the headache.**

**Normal installation is the way to go IMO.**

Comment: Indeed I've enabled both CKeditor module and Text editor modules...

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot, not even my Admin role exists, which is quite puzzling. Perhaps I need to enable a module? ugh.. minimal installation makes me sick, lol.

Comment: Indeed, I should have created the "Administrator" role from a scratch and install a Firefox "Check multiple boxes" add-on to check all the permission boxes for it lol...